# Editing server time for a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, time

I have changed the way i save the time when a log is submitted to the DB by using the 'datetime' stamp in MySQL.

Im saving it in this format **date("Y-m-d G:i:s");** which outputs it like so: **2012-02-22 20:20:01**

The only problem is im in the UK, and my hosting/server isnt.

I have found out how to edit the time to bring it inline with UK time by doing this: 
**date = date("Y-m-d G:i:s", strtotime("+14"));**

So now i have the time right i thought i would be ok, but now i have noticed that the date is not inline with UK date/time.

If i did a submission now it would display: **2012-02-22 20:25:36** when the time/date is actually **2012-02-23 20:20:01**.

So it looks like that because my script is 14 hours behind, its knocking the date out to.

Is there a way i can fix it ?

Thanks, Sam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include this in your program

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

Comment: that will only be specific for a single script. this is not a global solution.

Comment: Sorry, but where do i add that ? I have a global config file with the **$date = date("Y-m-d G:i:s", strtotime("+14"));** then i just type $date where i need to in my MySQL queries.

Comment: you can add it at the top of your program. you dont need to use  $date = date("Y-m-d G:i:s", strtotime("+14")); to convert at all.

Answer (score 1):

Add this one line in your php.ini file:

```
date.timezone = "Europe/London"
```

Now, anytime you use date or time functions, it will be adjusted to what you have specified.

For a complete list of timezones in Europe:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the PHP Datetime module: [Supported Timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Kiritimati'); // Change this to YOUR needed Timezone
$datetime_GMT  = new DateTime(strtotime($server_or_SQL_date));
$datetime_GMT->setTimezone($tz);
$datetime_GMT->format("Y-m-d G:i:s");
echo $datetime_GMT;
```